# Unique solutions on system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

If the system of equations $Ax=b$ is consistent for every $b∈R^n$, then the solution of the system of equations is always unique.
True,
False

Would the solution be unique if the bottom row of matrix A was all zero? Because wouldn't that mean the solution would be infinite. Or is the bottom row having all zero's impossible because maybe the system is consistent for every $b∈R^n$?

Comment: Let's say the bottom row of $A$ was all zeros, and let's take the bottom element of $b$ to be $1$ for specificity. (Any nonzero value will do.) If you convert the last row into an equation, does it have at least one solution? (If not, then $Ax=b$ is not consistent.)

Comment: @Semiclassical So if $b$ had a zero element in the bottom element, then wouldn't the solution be infinite. But can $b$ have a bottom zero because of $b∈R^n$ ?

Comment: Yes, and such $b$ is possible. But the premise of your proposition requires that the system be consistent for _all_ $b$. So if there's even one $b$ which makes the system inconsistent, then what you have will not be relevant to the proposition at hand.

Comment: @Semiclassical Ah ok, so $b$ having a zero element in the bottom row and having $A$ all zeroes would make the system inconsistent. Or if that happened would $b$ lose a dimension and not be $R^n$

Comment: No, this is backwards. If the bottom row of $A$ were zero and so was the bottom element of $b$, then the equation is $0x_1+0x_2+\cdots +0x_n=0$. That does have infinitely many solutions and so does not render the system $Ax=b$ inconsistent. The problem is that the bottom element of $b$ could be nonzero, because in that case no solution can possibly exist. So if the last row of $A$ is zeros, then there exists (many) $b$ such that $Ax=b$ is inconsistent.

Comment: @Semiclassical Yeah that makes sense now, was just the weird wording

Comment: With regard to the 1st paragraph, $x+y=b$ is consistent for all $b$ in $\bf R$, but there is never a unique solution.